# PostgreSQL Subqueries One-To-Many Relationship Search

Tags: sql, postgresql, one-to-many

```
employee_id | first_name | last_name
--------------------------------------
00001         Tim          Smith
00002         John         Doe

employee_id | skill_id
--------------------------------------
00001         1
00001         2
00002         1
00002         3

skill_id | name
--------------------------------------
1          Java
2          PHP
3          MySQL
```

I want to select all employees with Java **AND** PHP skills. With my sample above it should return

```
employee_id | first_name | last_name
--------------------------------------
00001         Tim          Smith
```

How can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
  FROM employee e JOIN employee_skills es
    ON es.employee_id = e.employee_id JOIN skills s
    ON es.skill_id = s.skill_id
 WHERE s.name IN('PHP', 'Java')
 GROUP BY e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.skill_id) = 2
```

If in your UI you already know skill_ids which you probably do, since you have ref table for it, then you don't even need second join

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
  FROM employee e JOIN employee_skills es
    ON es.employee_id = e.employee_id 
 WHERE es.skill_id IN(1, 2)
 GROUP BY e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT es.skill_id) = 2
```

Output:

```
| EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
----------------------------------------
|           1 |        Tim |     Smith |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/63dd5/5)** demo

Comment: Instead of this `WHERE s.name IN('PHP', 'Java')`

Can I use something like this `to_tsvector(s.name) @@ to_tsquery('PHP | Java')`

Comment: @nelsonjuan Probably. But why do want to do this? I'd suggest to opt-out from using skill names in queries at all and use them only in UI (if it's a possibility in your application).

Comment: I am actually using it for a search function to look for a resource with a set of skill set. Aside from the skill name I am also searching through the skill's description.

Comment: UI is actually is a text input. No skill id's on the UI.